# Angular 11 - text-decoration: line-through does not work properly with class binding

Tags: css, angular, binding, angular11, angular-ng-class

So I am making a todo app and I want to add stroke to the done tasks but the problem is that it is not working properly.

my .css file

```
.stroke{
    text-decoration: line-through
}
```

and the element in the .html file

```
<div *ngFor="..." [class.stroke]="task.isDone">Task Text </div>
```

What is happening is that whatever value isDone have at first will determine whether or not the item gets the stroke. Because when I toggle it later on, it doesn't change but it should!

This is how it looks when it is first loaded.

[image]

But when I uncheck it. The line through doesn't go away

[image]

and yes I am binding `task.isDone` with the checkbox

```
[(checked)]="task.isDone"
[class.stroke]="task.isDone"
```

I tried it on the latest version of chrome & latest version of Safari

Has anyone faced a similar issue with the text-decoration property?

Comment: Can you attach the data for tasks to the question?

Comment: please check it out now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `[(ngModel)]` binding.

```
<div *ngFor="let task of tasks" [class.stroke]="task.isDone">
  <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="task.isDone" />
  {{ task.name }}
</div>
```

OR

With `(change)` event and `[checked]` binding.

```
<div *ngFor="let task of tasks" [class.stroke]="task.isDone">
  <input type="checkbox" [checked]="task.isDone" (change)="task.isDone = !task.isDone" />
  {{ task.name }}
</div>
```

[Sample Solution on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jmnjzh?file=src/app/app.component.html)